# Delphi Android filter table sensitive with lowercase and uppercase

Tags: android, delphi, filter, case-sensitive

I am making a filter for my sqlite table using this formula. All goes well, but it is very sensitive to uppercase and lowercase letters. How to be insensitive with upper and lower case letters?

```
fdtableTab1Edit.Active := true;
             fdtableTab1Edit.Filtered := false;
             fdtableTab1Edit.Filter :=  'PRODUCK like ' +
             QuotedStr('%'+edit1.text+'%')+' or CODE like ' +
             QuotedStr('%'+edit1.text+'%')+' or TOTAL like ' +
             QuotedStr('%'+edit1.text+'%');
             fdtableTab1Edit.filtered := true;
             fdtableTab1Edit.Refresh;
             Edit1.Text := '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `FilterOptions` to do case insensitive comparisons instead of the default case sensitive.

```
fdtableTab1Edit.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
```

ref: [Setting Filter Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Setting_Filter_Options)

Comment: Works very well, it can be also done with TFDQuery. Thanks a ton!